# Expo-Constants failing Jest since swap to app.config.json

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

As stated in the title, I've recently switched our project from app.json to app.config.json ready for EAS builds in Expo. Since then, my simple App.test.js has been failing

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'environment' of undefined

 const enableInExpoDevelopment = Constants.manifest.extra.environment !== 'Development'
```

This is the App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from '../App';
describe('<App />', () => {
  it('has 1 child', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
    expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

And this is the current jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': require.resolve('react-native/jest/preprocessor.js')
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced- 
    element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react- 
    navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry- 
    expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)'
  ],
  reporters: [
    'default'
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    './__mocks__/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage.js'
  ]
}
```